# What is the source for the six kalimas?

Tags: quran, hadith, source-identification

This question is about the "[Six Kalimas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Kalimas)".

I recently attended the marriage ceremony of a friend, where the Imam or Khatib was of South-Asian origin. At the very  start of the ceremony he asked the bridegroom to recite the first two kalimas, I think that his purpose was to ascertain that the groom was a Muslim.

In later discussion and research I found out that in their basic religious education they are taught to memorize six "kalimas" which are as follows:

1. Kalimah Tayyibah kalimat aṭ-ṭaiyibah (Word of Purity)

   لَا إِلٰهَ إِلَّا الله مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُولُ الله‎
2. Kalimah Shahadah kalimat ash-shahādah (Word of Evidence)

   أَشْهَدُ أنْ لا إلَٰهَ إِلَّا اللهُ وَحْدَهُ لَا شَرِيْكَ لَهُ وَأشْهَدُ أنَّ مُحَمَّدًا عَبْدُهُ وَرَسُولُهُ‎
3. Kalimah Tamjeed kalimat at-tamjīd (Word of Majesty)

   سُبْحَان اللهِ وَالْحَمْدُلِلّهِ وَلا إِلهَ إِلّااللّهُ وَاللّهُ أكْبَرُ وَلا حَوْلَ وَلاَ قُوَّةَ إِلَّا بِاللّهِ الْعَلِيِّ الْعَظِيْم
4. Kalimah Tawheed kalimat at-tawḥīd (Word of Oneness)

   لَآ اِلٰهَ اِلَّا اللهُ وَحْدَهٗ لَا شَرِيْكَ لَهٗ لَهُ الْمُلْكُ وَ لَهُ الْحَمْدُ يُحْىٖ وَ يُمِيْتُ وَ هُوَحَیٌّ لَّا يَمُوْتُ اَبَدًا اَبَدًاؕ ذُو الْجَلَالِ وَالْاِكْرَامِؕ بِيَدِهِ الْخَيْرُؕ وَهُوَ عَلٰى كُلِّ شیْ ٍٔ قَدِیْرٌؕ‎
5. Kalimah Istighfar (Word of Penitence)

   اَسْتَغْفِرُ اللهِ رَبِّىْ مِنْ كُلِِّ ذَنْۢبٍ اَذْنَبْتُهٗ عَمَدًا اَوْ خَطَا ًٔ سِرًّا اَوْ عَلَانِيَةً وَّاَتُوْبُ اِلَيْهِ مِنَ الذَّنْۢبِ الَّذِیْٓ اَعْلَمُ وَ مِنَ الذَّنْۢبِ الَّذِىْ لَآ اَعْلَمُ اِنَّكَ اَنْتَ عَلَّامُ الْغُيُوْبِ وَ سَتَّارُ الْعُيُوْبِ و َغَفَّارُ الذُّنُوْبِ وَ لَا حَوْلَ وَلَا قُوَّةَ اِلَّا بِاللهِ الْعَلِىِِّ الْعَظِيْمِؕ‎
6. Kalima Radde Kufr ("Word of Rejection of Disbelief")

   اَللّٰهُمَّ اِنِّیْٓ اَعُوْذُ بِكَ مِنْ اَنْ اُشْرِكَ بِكَ شَيْئًا وَّاَنَآ اَعْلَمُ بِهٖ وَ اَسْتَغْفِرُكَ لِمَا لَآ اَعْلَمُ بِهٖ تُبْتُ عَنْهُ وَ تَبَرَّأْتُ مِنَ الْكُفْرِ وَ الشِّرْكِ وَ الْكِذْبِ وَ الْغِيْبَةِ وَ الْبِدْعَةِ وَ النَّمِيْمَةِ وَ الْفَوَاحِشِ وَ الْبُهْتَانِ وَ الْمَعَاصِىْ كُلِِّهَا وَ اَسْلَمْتُ وَ اَقُوْلُ لَآ اِلٰهَ اِلَّا اللهُ مُحَمَّدٌ رَّسُوْلُ اللهِؕ‎

I would like to know the source (Quran or Hadith reference) of each of these statements or duas, especially the last four.

Comment: Just in case, there's also the Wikipedia article for [Six Kalimas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Kalimas).